# Apache Wamp [error] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters

Tags: apache, ssl

When I set in `httpd-ssl.conf`:

```
CustomLog “C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.11/logs/ssl_request.log” \
       "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
```

I get:

```
Apache Wamp [error] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters:invalid transfer log path \x93C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.11/logs/ssl_request.log\x94.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the error `\x93C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.11/logs/ssl_request.log\x94.`, we can see that the invalid characters are the first and the last ones. It corresponds with "double quotes".

Use `"`  instead of `“`.